# How to organize hashes by property

Tags: ruby, hashmap

Here is the hashes that will be processed:

```
{
      "flatiron school bk" => {
        :location => "NYC"
      },
      "flatiron school" => {
        :location => "NYC"
      },
      "dev boot camp" => {
        :location => "SF"
      },
      "dev boot camp chicago" => {
        :location => "Chicago"
      },
      "general assembly" => {
        :location => "NYC"
      },
      "Hack Reactor" => {
        :location => "SF"
      }
}
```

I need to organize these hashes by location, like this:

```
{    "NYC"=>["flatiron school bk", "flatiron school", "general assembly"],
     "SF"=>["dev boot camp", "Hack Reactor"],
     "Chicago"=>["dev boot camp chicago"]}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use each_with_object to combine in into new hash:

```
hash.each_with_object({}) do |(name, data), res|
  (res[data[:location]] ||= []) << name
end
```

**Explanation:**

[each_with_object](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object)
Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object given, and returns the initially given object.

In this case name and data is key and value of each element in given hash. 
In `(res[data[:location]] ||= []) << name` you get location, create array in result hash for given location (if it doesn't exist), then put key of input hash to it.

Comment: @StevenKwok add explanation